# How to update the input text value using custom Directive in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am newer in angularjs. I am just trying to update the input txt value using custom Directive. But i cant. Here i have showed my code What i did wrong this code. Some one help me and explain how it is working.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});
myApp.controller('MyCtrl',MyCtrl);
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
    $scope.myTime = '10:59';
}


myApp.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function (v) {
                console.log('value changed, new value is: ' + v);
               ngModel.$setViewValue('11')
               //scope.ngModel = '11'
               
            });
        }
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Hello, {{name}}!
    
    
    <input type="text" my-directive ng-model="myTime" name="customTime">
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should register your `MyCtrl` controller in your `myApp` module like below.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',MyCtrl);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
    $scope.myTime = '10:59';
}
```

If you need to update the text field value to some desired value, once you're done with the update in the watcher using $setViewValue(), you need to call `$render()` as well on `NgModelController`.

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
    scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function (v) {
        console.log('value changed, new value is: ' + v);
       ngModel.$setViewValue('11');
       ngModel.$render();
    });
}
```

Here's a [Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QjvYMW?editors=101) to check this change.

Comment: I thought you're just trying to capture the updated value in your watcher, if you need to update the text field to some desired value, you need to call `$render()` as well after `$setViewValue()`. Updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Comment: Thank you so much friend :)